# How to Remove brew install bash

Tags: bash, homebrew

I installed bash via brew to check out version 4.  I would like to remove this.  I cannot use my npm packages correctly and am at a standstill.  Wondering how to remove an installation from homebrew?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried `brew uninstall bash`?

If that doesn't work for you, you could try removing the actual files, usually `/usr/local/Cellar/bash/` and `/usr/local/bin/bash`. This should get you at least far enough to be using your old `bash` binaries, from where you could do any further cleanup.

Comment: I went into the folder Library >> Caches >> Homebrew >> it is there bash-4.3.42.el_capitan.bottle.tar.gz.    remove this file from homebrew

Comment: That's just the source file that HomeBrew downloaded. You don't need to remove it after the installation itself is removed.